# Close child window whenever mouse leave in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

```
private void myChildWindow_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.close();
    }
```

Wanted to close child window when ever mouse leave from that window in silver light.Like face book.[image]

I'm able to show child window when ever mouse hover on Parent Window Hyper Link,But i'm not able to close child window when ever mouse leave.Above is the code snippet i have written.

Comment: On the Parent Window try implementing Leave (Event Handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ChildWindow control has an Overlay which stretch's to fill the entire available area of the Silverlight application.  So a mouse leave event on the child window won't fire until your mouse leaves the overlay.  You need to put the mouse leave event on the root layout container of your child window content. Here is an example:

```
    private void ShowButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChildWindow cw = new ChildWindow();
        cw.Width = 300;
        cw.Height = 300;
        cw.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        cw.VerticalContentAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        Grid g = new Grid();
        g.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        g.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Child window content." });
        g.MouseLeave += ChildWindowContent_MouseLeave;
        cw.Content = g;
        cw.Show();
    }

    private void ChildWindowContent_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ChildWindow cw = ((Grid)sender).Parent as ChildWindow;
        cw.Close();
    }
```

More info on the ChildWindow control can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You would have to call the following Event Handler on your Parent Window:

```
    private void ParentWindow_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myChildWindow.Close();
    }
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Parent to Child,Not child to parent.you are writting child window name in parent window how it's possible??

Comment: If you have: class ChildWindow:ParentWindow (means inherited from parent) then ofcourse its impossible. I thought your ParentWindow contains 'myChildWindow' as a composed (through composition) object. Are you sure you need to inherit from your Parent Window? (or may be composition seems to me a better option though!!).